# How to get database entries having an exact match with list contents

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, subquery

I have the following table :

```
  create_table "report_tags", force: true do |t|
   t.integer  "report_id"
   t.string   "tag",          limit: 20
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

The table has the following contents :

```
+----+-----------+--------+
| id | report_id |  tag   |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 |         1 | foo    |
|  2 |         1 | bar    |
|  3 |         2 | foo    |
|  4 |         2 | bar    |
|  5 |         2 | foobar |
|  6 |         3 | foo    |
|  7 |         3 | t2     |
+----+-----------+--------+
```

If the user gives me a String that contains some tags that I need to find out if I have in a specific report.

In other words if the user provides me the `String "foo,bar"` I want to return the report_id 1 because this is the one that has the tags foo and bar.

Is it possible to do this with a Mysql query ? Since my application uses Active Record as a persistence framework is it possible to do it easier using Active Record ?

PS : The user may give an arbitrary number of tags

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to return a report_id if every one of the report's tag is in the list AND every one of the list's tags is associated with the report? (In your example, report #2 is not included because foobar is not in the list and report#3 is not included because the report is not also tagged 'bar')

Comment: @AgRizzo : I want to return the report_ids that have an exact match. The tags in the String should belong to the report and no more. Report #2 should not be included because is has one additional tag and Report#3 should not be included because it does not have the tag bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user is only allowed to enter the search terms in order then the following would work:

```
SELECT mq.report_id
FROM 
(
  SELECT t.report_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag ORDER BY t.id SEPARATOR ',') AS ConcatTag
  FROM MyTable AS t
  GROUP BY t.report_id
) AS mq
WHERE mq.ConcatTag = 'foo,bar'
```

The following would also work:

```
SELECT t.report_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag ORDER BY t.id SEPARATOR ',') AS ConcatTag
FROM MyTable AS t
GROUP BY t.report_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag ORDER BY t.id SEPARATOR ',') = 'foo,bar'
```

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7894c/5/1) that demonstrates the above.

Comment: Couldn't you use 1 query and change the WHERE clause into a `HAVING WHERE mq.ConcatTag = 'foo,bar'?

Comment: @Linger: Well it works but since the user is not necessarily providing the search terms in order if you change the `ORDER BY t.id` to `ORDER BY t.tag` and you also sort the String from the user accordingly then it will work in every possible scenario right ??

Comment: @AgRizzo: The internal query is used to sort the table contents. If you remove it how can you get them sorted ?

Comment: @Stefanos if you can logically sort the `t.tag` then yes it would work only if the user is entering the string in order.  For this method to work the order of the string coming in must match the ORDER By clause you specify in the query.

Comment: @linger: Since the tag is a String you can sort it in any case right ? So I can just take care to sort the same way all the time :)

Answer (score 1):

The following SQL query does the job of finding those `report_id`s that have all the tags specified **EDIT: and no others**. I can't think of a way to translate it into AREL, but there still be a more straightforward method.

```
SELECT report_id, SUM(contribute) as sum FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT report_id, tag, 1 as contribute FROM report_ids 
   WHERE tag IN ('foo', 'bar')
   UNION 
   SELECT DISTINCT report_id, tag, -1 as contribute FROM report_ids 
   WHERE tag NOT IN ('foo', 'bar')) 
GROUP BY report_id HAVING sum = 2;
```

(2, of course, is the number of distinct tags you're searching for)

Comment: This will also return report_id 2 which is invalid since it contains one more tag (foobar). How can we fix this ?

Comment: Well now the problem is that is also returns the report_id #3 probably because it has two tags :(

Comment: Ah, sorry; try now (should be `SUM`, not `COUNT`)

Answer (score 0):

```
ReportTag.select(:id).where(tag: 'foo')
```

Comment: Since the String is : str = "foo,bar" , I execute the following command : ReportTag.select(:report_id).where(tag: str_arr) where str_arr is the String as an Array but instead of getting only the report_id 2 I get the rest as well ...